# What are the good and bad points of TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope

What are the good and bad points of the `TransactionScope` class in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Bad:

[TransactionScope's timeout feature sucks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288475).

Answer (score 5):

Some advantages from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx) :

TransactionScope Benefits

- The code inside the transactional
  scope is not only transactional, it
  is also promotable. The transaction
  starts with the LTM and
  System.Transactions will promote it
  as required, according to the nature
  of its interaction with the resources
  or remote objects.
- The scope is independent of the
  application object model—any piece of
  code can use the TransactionScope and
  thus become transactional. There is
  no need for special base class or
  attributes.
- There is no need to enlist resources
  explicitly with the transaction. Any
  System.Transactions resource manager
  will detect the ambient transaction
  created by the scope and
  automatically enlist.
- Overall, it is a simple and intuitive
  programming model even for the more
  complex scenarios that involve
  transaction flow and nesting.

Answer (score 3):

Good side:

Can do transactions beyond database context. Insert record into db. Write file to disk.

Bad side:

Requires MSDTC access on client machine, where TransactionScope is used.

Comment: Doesn't it only require access when you connect to 2 or more different servers?  It starts off lightweight then upgrades itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to / clarify the points Incognito makes:

- TransactionScopes make the implementation of ACID transactions simple (i.e. so you don't need to write explicit "rollback" or cleanup code)
- TransactionScope can coordinate resources such as Databases, Message Queues and Transactional File Systems under a transaction
- Re TransactionScopes are intuitive - resources such as SQL etc will automatically / seamlessly detect the ambient transaction and enlist as available.

The only 'bad' side is that you need to be aware that:

- The default isolation level of TransactionScope is READ SERIALIZABLE, which is usually too 'strong' and can cause blocking and deadlocking. Would recommend using ReadCommitted for most transactions.
- TransactionScope will escalate a transaction to DTC if more than one database / more than one concurrent connection / more than one resource (e.g. SQL and MSMQ) are used in a TransactionScope. But you can usually avoided in Single Threaded / single database scenarios by closing connections before opening a new one (or keeping one connection open throughout, which isn't recommended).